# Three.js doesn't play animation in React

Tags: three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I load GLTF model downloaded from Sketchfab in React app. Model loads perfectly well, but animation doesn`t play at all. I tried different approaches. Any ideas?

```js
function Model({ url }) {

  const model = useRef()
  const { scene, animations } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url)
  const [mixer] = useState(() => new THREE.AnimationMixer())
  useEffect(() => void mixer.clipAction(animations[0], group.current).play(), [])


  return(
        <primitive
          ref={model}
          object={scene}
        />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

1. I had to use node instead of scene and select **"RootNode"** (console.log node and choose what seemed to me the main node, the model contained a dozen of nodes)
2. Update mixer by frames with **useFrame**
3. Apply animation to the model (a bit updated)

Working code:

```js
function Model({ url }) {

   const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, scene, materials, animations } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url)
 const actions = useRef()
  const [mixer] = useState(() => new THREE.AnimationMixer())
  useFrame((state, delta) => mixer.update(delta))
  useEffect(() => {
    actions.current = { idle: mixer.clipAction(animations[0], group.current) }
    actions.current.idle.play()
    return () => animations.forEach((clip) => mixer.uncacheClip(clip))
  }, [])


  return(
     <group ref={group} dispose={null}>
        <primitive
          ref={group}
          name="Object_0"
          object={nodes["RootNode"]}
        />
        </group>
  )
}
```

Now it works

Comment: check this out https://twitter.com/0xca0a/status/1336056832025047041

Answer (score 0):

You need to call mixer.update(delta) in useFrame inside your component:

```
    import { useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber'
    function Model({url}) {
    .
    . 
    .
        useFrame((scene, delta) => {
            mixer?.update(delta)
        })
    .
    . 
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

- Put your glb file inside public filer.

```js
import { Suspense, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useAnimations, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

export const Character = (props: any) => {
  const ref = useRef() as any;

  const glf = useGLTF("assets/Soldier.glb");
  const { actions } = useAnimations(glf.animations, ref);

  useEffect(() => {
    actions.Run?.play();
  });

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <primitive 
        ref={ref} 
        object={glf.scene}
      />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```